# Asking sign in to Zendesk when end user trying to view attachment from application

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core

users asking to login to zendesk when clicking on domain specific attachment link with content_url from external application how to avoid sign in

how to avoid sign in, and is there any other way to change code to facilitate users

Comment: Hi, what does "change code to facilitate users" mean?